# Is there a usage like "come do something"?

Tags: grammar

From NPR:

> So go ahead, join the entomologists and hope for another even colder polar vortex to ***come settle*** over the country again this winter.

I guess the word "settle" is used as a verb here. So does the word "come" have a usage like "come do something"? I couldn't find the usage in the dictionary. Could you give me some more examples like "come settle"? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's common in informal American English (hat tip: @Damkerng) to omit the word "and" from the phrase "come and X". For example, the following pairs of sentences are equivalent:

> Why don't you come and watch the movie with us?
>   Why don't you come watch the movie with us?
>
> He can come and write his essay in our room.
>   He can come write his essay in our room.

Similarly, the phrase "come settle" in your sentence means the same thing as "come and settle".

Comment: *Practical English Usage* notes this usage as *informal American English* under entry 53.3.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Good to know! I just assumed it was universal. :-)